# liquibase is putting single quote around all values of a csv line for the insert sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, liquibase

This is what I have in the csv file:

```
CONTACT_TYP_CD,CONTACT_TYP_DESC,CREATE_DATE,CREATE_USER,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_USER
"ALL","Contact to be used for all communications","2014-03-14 00:00:00","CS_MAIN",null,null
```

This is how I load this file through liquibase:

```
<loadData file="src/main/resources/METAINF/install/seed_data/seed_contact_type.csv"
        tableName="CONTACT_TYPE">
</loadData>
```

This is what liquibase uses to insert the data into oracle:

```
liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Error executing SQL INSERT INTO CONTACT_TYPE (CONTACT_TYP_CD,CONTACT_TYP_DESC,CREATE_DATE,CREATE_USER,UPDATE_DATE,UPDATE_USER) VALUES ('"LL","Contact to be used for all communications","2014-03-14 00:00:00","CS_MAIN",null,null'): ORA-00947: not enough values
```

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the double quotes from your csv file, and define columns types, see the following test case as an example:

[changeSet source](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/6018c674542ecf6c430f0541a2bf1ac655d9a647/liquibase-integration-tests/src/test/resources/changelogs/common/smartDataLoad.changelog.xml#L58)

[csv file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/liquibase/liquibase/master/liquibase-core/src/test/resources/liquibase/change/core/sample.data2.csv)

Another solution might be to enclose also the column titles in quotes, as seen [here](https://liquibase.jira.com/browse/CORE-1035)

Answer (score 2):

you need to add the xml escape for double quote in the quotechar

```
quotchar="&quot;"
```

Comment: Look at that, it escaped my double quote in my response.  set it to quotechar=" & quot;"  I added the space around the & so it would post.

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem here is the separator, not the quote. Liquibase seems to use semikolons by default, so you have to specify `separator=","`. Otherwise the whole line is considered a single value.